# Why is freshly opened Workbook.Name different from Workbook title in Excel window?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a file and referenced it as `GlobalFile`.
Then I saved it as "Glo" and then as "Ume". Then I reopen the saved files to have two distinct workbooks open on two different names in two different Workbook objects: `GlobalFile` and `NightMareFile`.

After opening, Excel windows has the correct headers as "Glo.xls" and "Ume.xls" respectively, but testing `NightMareFile.Name` results in "Glo.xlsx" !!!

How is this possible at all?

---

I'm on Win 10 64 bit, Excel 365 16 bit.

Already tried:

- DoEvents before or after Open
- RefreshAll after open
- Excel restart brought no change.

What makes me pull my hair: Changing the order of the two open blocks fixes the name conflict: if "Ume" is opened first it has the correct name, as does "Glo".

Originally I had more named file versions saved and reopened, but only this one was always faulty, hence the new name: NightMareFile. No matter how I changed the order of files to open, this one always inherited the name of the file opened before him into another object variable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main_control_routine()

    Dim GlobalFile As Workbook
    Dim NightMareFile As Workbook

    Set GlobalFile = Workbooks.Add
    Debug.Print "GlobalFile.Name: " & GlobalFile.Name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    GlobalFile.SaveAs Filename:="Glo"
    Debug.Print "GLOBAL File ready!"

    'GlobalFile save as Ume
    GlobalFile.SaveAs Filename:="Ume"
    Debug.Print "GlobalFile.Name: As Ume " & GlobalFile.Name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'GLOBAL reopened to GlobalFile
    Set GlobalFile = Workbooks.Open("Glo", False)
    Debug.Print "GlobalFile.Name: " & GlobalFile.Name

    'Ume reopened to NightMareFile
    Set NightMareFile = Workbooks.Open("Ume", False)
    Debug.Print "NightMareFile.Name: " & NightMareFile.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your code to add the debug.print outputs

Comment: You haven't closed either of the new files you created by saving `GlobalFile`

Comment: If a workbook with the same name as the one you're trying to open is already open, and you're trying to set a workbook.object to the return value of the `Open()` method, then the end result can be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: as of Sept 2023 (Excel 365, Version 2307, and maybe before that) it looks like this issue has been resolved.**  You may still want to check, if you're running an older version.

---

If a workbook with the same name as the one you're trying to open is already open, and you're trying to assign a workbook object variable to the return value of the `Open()` method, then the end result can be unpredictable.

For example - if I run this with both workbooks "Glo" and "Ume" already open:

```
Sub main_control_routine()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Glo.xlsx", False)
    Debug.Print wb.Name
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Ume.xlsx", False)
    Debug.Print wb.Name
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Glo.xlsx", False)
    Debug.Print wb.Name
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Ume.xlsx", False)
    Debug.Print wb.Name
    
End Sub
```

...this is the output:

```
Ume.xlsx
Ume.xlsx
Ume.xlsx
Ume.xlsx
```

Not what you'd expect.

In my testing it looks like instead of getting the intended workbook it returns a reference to the last-opened workbook.

The fix would be to always check if the workbook is already open before using `Workbooks.Open()` to get a reference to it.

Comment: Thx! For me it seems that if I would open a file onto a same named file already open, Excel would at least throw an error... I see NightMareFile as a brand new Reference to a freshly opened file. Excel indeed opens it, and says on the Excel window header: Ume.xlsx. And the name is Glo. I tis difficult for me to believe Excel lets me do something leading to this contradiction.

Comment: I think it's possible a lot of people get caught out by this, and it's definitely something you'd expect to raise an error or warning, rather than just return a "random" other workbook to your variable.

Comment: Thank You Tim!  Closing GlobalFile after the last Save.As seems to solve the problem, or at least I am on track now to finish my project.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've been able to test this now (yesterday was too busy) and I can't seem to cause your same issue to occur. Did it get patched over the years, you think? If possible, can you re-do your test to see if you still get your earlier findings? I always got back the workbook that was intended with the full reference (I suppose the "Glo.xslx" was just an abbreviation for something like "D:\test\Glo.xslx")

Comment: @Notus_Panda - Yes it looks like it's nor fixed (at least in my version of Excel).  I don't know when that might have been resolved.  I've edited the answer to add that.