# Workbook object ref' overwritten by second workbook object- Excel Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Excel Office 365 Version 1902 (Build 11328.20420)

When two workbook objects are created and set to different excel files (using Application.Workbooks.Open) the second workbook object reference is somehow overwritten and points to the first file.

I encountered this problem whilst rewriting code in an existing spreadsheet application at work. The new code opens two excel files concurrently setting each excel workbook object to a file. The first time the method runs the expected behaviour is exhibited., the two objects point to their respective files. On the second and subsequent runs the first object seems to be overwritten by the second object and both objects point to the same file. I recreated this in a test method see below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

On Error GoTo err_handler

Dim Book1 As Workbook
Dim Book2 As Workbook

Set Book1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Book1.xlsx")
Set Book2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Book2.xlsx")

Debug.Print Book1.Name
Debug.Print Book2.Name

Exit Sub

err_handler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

The code produces this set of results

Run 1:

> Book1.xlsx
>
> Book2.xlsx

Run 2:

> Book2.xlsx
>
> Book2.xlsx

This issue is specific to Office 365. I tested the same code in Office 2016 and there is no issue.

Office 2016 results:

Run 1:

> Book1.xlsx
>
> Book2.xlsx

Run 2:

> Book1.xlsx
>
> Book2.xlsx

Is this a known issue that has been corrected in later versions of Office 365 or something new?

EDIT

It is yet to be explained why this behavior appears to be specific to Excel 365. The prior answer does not explain why this happens it merely states an observation that unpredictable behavior can occur when open workbooks are reopened. I did not see this same behavior when running the code using Excel 2016 (not Office 365)

Many thanks,

Simon.

Comment: Just to check - were Book1 and Book2 both closed before you ran this? Calling `Workbook.Open` on an already open workbook can cause issues.

Comment: They are not closed. I've just re-run the code with the workbooks closed and there is no problem. It is strange this doesn't happen in Excel 2016.

Comment: There have been previous similar questions here on SO, if I remember correctly. I don't know if they were tied to a specific version of Excel.

Comment: OK, I am happy to delete this post if required. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56260958/9245853) is pretty similar, and it looks like it's Excel 365, interesting.

Comment: I agree, it's the same problem and interestingly also using Office 365. In the section of code I was debugging I had a break point which was hit before the workbooks were closed which has caused this problem to arise. So it is no longer a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is freshly opened Workbook.Name different from Workbook title in Excel window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260958/why-is-freshly-opened-workbook-name-different-from-workbook-title-in-excel-windo)

Comment: I think the question, 'Why does this happen?' is still yet to be answered.