# Function not using the right range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a function I got from Excel tips to get the row of the first partial match of a name.

The idea of all this is to track holidays.
I have one special spreadsheet being used as a database where I store all the data. Every change made is stored in the data spreadsheet which in in our cloud. That is used to spread the data into other computers using copy paste to every workspaces sheet.

My issue is sometimes the function being used searches for the employee using the wrong range.

This is the function code:

```
Function FirstPartMatch(str As String, rng As Range)
Dim tmp As Long
Dim position As Long
Dim cll As Range

position = 0
tmp = 0

For Each cll In rng
    
    tmp = tmp + 1
    If InStr(1, LCase(cll.Value2), LCase(str)) > 0 Then
        
        position = tmp
        Exit For
    
    End If

Next cll

If position Then
    
    FirstPartMatch = position

Else
 
    FirstPartMatch = "#NA"

End If

End Function
```

Here is my code that we use to add holidays via a form:

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
Dim name As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vdate As Date
Dim agency As String
Dim code As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim Rlastrow As Long
Dim holiday As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

open_wb_onedrive 'open data file
Set ws = openwb.Worksheets("data") 'assign sheet of data file to variable

With ws
    
    .Unprotect Password:=pass
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'finds first empty row of the holidays column
    Rlastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'finds the first empty row of the employee column
    
    'assign the imput data to variables
    name = Me.cmbName.value
    agency = Me.cmbPosition.value
    vdate = CDate(Me.cmbDate.value)
            
    'Checks if name is already in holiday column, and skips the code if it is
    If FirstPartMatch(name, .Range("V1:V" & lastrow)) > 0 Then
            
        MsgBox ("Holiday already exists")
        GoTo Skip
    
    Else
        
        'Adds data if new name on holiday list
        .Cells(lastrow, 22).value = name
        .Cells(lastrow, 23).value = vdate
        
        holiday = FirstPartMatch(name, .Range("A1:A" & Rlastrow)) 'finds in which row the employee is
        .Cells(holiday, 1).value = name & " Holiday until " & vdate 'ads the holiday info
        
    End If
    
    .Protect Password:=pass
    
End With

'end of sub code to close the data file
Skip:
get_data ws
Unload Me
End Sub
```

The issue on the code happens on this if part:

```
If FirstPartMatch(name, .Range("V1:V" & lastrow)) > 0 Then
```

Instead of searching on the data file in column V, the code does the search on my original file and sheet on column A. (where the code is being run)

I wonder where is my mistake as I don't reference the code spreadsheet or sheet in the whole code and just use it to display my data mirrored from my other file.

Code for open_wb_onedrive as requested:

```
Sub open_wb_onedrive()
   Dim wbFullName
   Set objLogExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   objLogExcel.Visible = True
   wbFullName = "https://onedrive_hidden_url/data.xlsx"
   Set openwb = objLogExcel.Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)
   
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd advise against using a global variable like it appears you're doing with `openwb`. Rewrite `open_wb_onedrive` so that it returns a `Workbook` object.

Comment: Please add the code for `open_wb_onedrive`   Does your "original file" have a worksheet named "data"?

Comment: Pls. try this. Before calling the function create a Range object and assign the Range to it something like this  `Dim passrange as Range : set passrange= .Range("V1:V" & lastrow)`. And replace in the calling function  the expression with the new variable. In this context you referenced the values of the range, because you not declared further property, or use it in a For Each expression (like in the called function)

Comment: @TimWilliams yes the new worksheet has a sheet name data. I added the code that I use to open the one drive

Comment: @BigBen as this is to open an onedrive document I need this to be in a sub

Comment: I sincerely doubt that. I bet you want a `Function` that returns a `Workbook`.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new instance of Excel in `open_wb_onedrive`?

Comment: Before opening `data.xlsx` you first need to check if it's already open.  Otherwise `openwb` may end up getting set to the wrong workbook.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262538/478884

Comment: @Blackcat unfortunately this did not work and produce same results as my code

Comment: @BigBen I do not want a workbook. I would like to update my workbook with the holiday data. The way I created my code is the best solution I have found when handling files on the cloud. Any other way the data sometimes does not copy/paste or write properly. I do not know why this is. However when opening a new instance the cloud file behaves accordingly

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the heads up about same name files being opened. I have a code to check data is not opened whenever a instance of the original file opens. Also part of the code ib get_data is to close the external data.xlsx file. So I never run with issues of same name files opened. My issue here is more that it is searching in the wrong range. (I thought the with would activate the sheet)

Comment: You do want a *reference* to a workbook though, and your current approach using a global variable is not optimal. Much better to use a `Function` here. Also, `With` is unrelated to activating, and you don't need to activate.

Comment: @BigBen if you find a better way of working with onedrive, please let me know. This is the one I found and for now it is working with most things. Only issue I am having is with this part of the code. This code even works well with excels Match, however I am looking for part of the string and not the full one

Comment: @beli I simulate your program in excel, and the only change i made was `FirstPartMatch = "#NA"` in this. i replaced "#NA" with `0` and the name appeared in the bottom of column V, and a text --Holiday until ... -- added to the corresponding name.

Comment: Your `With ws` would scope those ranges to the correct sheet, so if that's not happening then there's something else going on which you've not shown us here.

Comment: @Blackcat if I remove the if, the code runs well and even finds the person correctly. My only issue is when it tries to reference the range on the if for some reason it doesn't go for the right range

Comment: @TimWilliams There is nothing more happening here. I exposed all the code and everything that happens. For me it is even stranger that the code works if I remove the if I as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround found: (Still baffled why part of the previous code works and part doesn't)

```
'Checks if name is already in holiday column, and skips the code if it is
    If InStr(1, LCase(name), LCase("holiday")) <> 0 Then
            
        MsgBox ("Holiday already exists")
        GoTo Skip
    
    Else
        
        'In the case it's not adds the data to the table
        .Cells(lastrow, 22).value = name
        .Cells(lastrow, 23).value = vdate
        
        holiday = FirstPartMatch(name, .Range("A1:A" & Rlastrow)) 'finds in which row the employee is
        .Cells(holiday, 1).value = name & " Holiday until " & vdate 'ads the holiday info
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `openwb` object is not available in the `cmdOK_Click` Sub. Place a

```
Dim openwb as Workbook
```

in the Declaration section of the module where the `open_wb_onedrive` Sub is.

Comment: I do have this. thanks