# VBA code that should open one workbook, instead opens another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a workbook through VBA and store it as a Workbook object to be handled by later code, but while I open the correct file, it stores another file in the variable.

I am using the following code to find the file I want to store in my variable.

```
Sub find_file()
    Dim correctFile As String
    Dim src As Workbook

    Set src = Nothing
    correctFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel File (*.xlsx*), *.xlsx*", Title:="Find file with data to be processed")
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(correctFile, True, True)
    
    Debug.Print "Stored filename is " & correctFile
    Debug.Print "Current file is " & src.Name
    
    Set src = Nothing
End Sub
```

Due to my confusion with the output, I input the two debug.print lines to see where the issue was and sure enough I got the following output:

```
Stored filename is C:\Users\username\Documents\foldername\FileA.xlsx
Current file is FileB.xlsx
```

This is less than ideal, since I need to work on FileA, not FileB

For the record, I have both files open (along with my code-file) for testing purposes, and if I close FileB, the code will correctly apply to FileA. As this code will be used by more people than me in the future, it will probably be ideal if they don't have to close all their open excel-files for this code to work.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: IN ADDITION TO GOOD COMMENTS FROM OTHER USERS, IT SEEMS THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED ALREADY AT stackoverflow.com/a/56262538/478884

Comment: Sounds as if you are working on the ActiveWorkbook. You should convert your Sub to a Function, return the opened Workbook, store that return value into a variable and use this to work on your file.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, I had FileB active, then ran the code and selected FileA, which was then correctly stored in the variable.

Comment: @FunThomas That may be a good idea, but trying that, I still get the same problem, that the function variable stores FileB rather than the desired FileA

Comment: @Notus_Panda That's frustrating, because I cannot get it to stop. I have tried closing Excel; tried moving the code from "ThisWorkbook" to a module of its own - still it persists for me. I have also tried a variety of combinations of documents, and it seems to have a certain order for which it prioritizes workbooks, but I cannot for the life of me see what that order should be. None of the other documents have competing macros.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You already assign the opened workbook ("correctFile") into a variable ("src"). So if you convert the sub into a function, assign that as function result (`Set FindFile = scr`). And, btw, remove the statement `Set src = Nothing`, it's completely useless anyhow.

Comment: @FunThomas I agree, but that's the issue I am currently trying to find out. 
As you can see slightly later in the code, I debug both correctFile and src, and as far as I can see, it should be the same value; the file being opened through the dialog option. 
But my issue is that for some reason that I do not understand, I end up with correctFile = FileA and src = FileB.
Switching it to a function is a sensible solution, but in this case I tried debugging it and still got findFile = FileB

Comment: Oh, I see, didn't notice that the Debug-statements are immediately after the open. Do you have any Trigger code running when the workbook is opened? Are you showing the complete code? I never saw that kind of behaviour.

Comment: @FunThomas I have been pulling my hair trying to find any possible source of the issue. I have even checked for other code that I could have forgotten about and there is nothing. I did have some additional code that should be executed afterwards, but I have tried cutting that out and into a txt-file for the time being, just in case, but the issue persists. 
I am currently trying to troubleshoot if the "open" keyword is the issue. Maybe the issue is that it cannot update the src variable, if the file is already open, and goes to last option, but that feels like a stretch

Comment: If you start afresh, brand new workbook - with just the macro above - does the issue persist?

Comment: @CLR I just tried starting fresh - and yes, my issue persists into the the brand new file. Even when trying with two brand new test files it still persists.
From my Immediate window:
Run 1: (open FileA)
Stored filename is C:\Users\username\Documents\FileA.xlsx
Current file is FileA.xlsx
Run 2: (open FileB. FileA is still open)
Stored filename is C:\Users\username\Documents\FileB.xlsx
Current file is FileB.xlsx
Run 3: (open FileA. FileA and FileB are both open)
Stored filename is C:\Users\username\Documents\FileA.xlsx
Current file is FileB.xlsx

Comment: Also **unable to replicate**. I used code as above with no files open, one file open or one plus the file to be selected. In all cases the immediate window output referred to the same chosen file each time.

Comment: Bummer - I really have no idea why this is happening. I appreciate the effort and assistance, but clearly this is something on my end - even if I have no idea what that might be.

Comment: Do not use `Workbooks.Open` on a file that is already open. It will fail silently. So first check whether you already have it open, and only open it if you don't.

Comment: I never *(hold wood)* had issues with `Workbooks.Open` on already opened files so I'd love to hear what "fail silently" has to do with this issue. Especially since both CLR and I have tested this on our own systems with open/closed files without issues. Is find_file triggered by anything @OP?

Comment: @Paul that was the conclusion I ended up at myself - and I have found a workaround to my problem by adding an if-statement testing if the file was open already or not and then either opening or just referencing it. It works, that it, the code does as it should now, which is nice, but still odd since the other commententers does not seem to have encountered any issues at that point.

Comment: @Notus_Panda as far as I can see find_file is not triggered by anything other than what I have shown you. Not anything I have added for that effect either. But Paul does seem to be right, and that is where my issue seemed to be, oddly enough, since no one else in the comments have had that issue. It works for now, but still, odd I think

Comment: @Notus_Panda - if you run something like `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(somePath)` and `somePath` is already open and *was not the last file opened*, you will instead get back a reference to the last file opened.  See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262538/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams I must've gotten real lucky with how I've written my code in some of my earlier projects with opening them first (even if they're already opened) and afterwards setting them to a variable. Thanks for the link, I'll be sure to tinker with that some more tomorrow.

Comment: Luckily it doesn’t come up much.  Only ever happened to me once…

Comment: @TimWilliams Well that explains pretty much all my issues with this code. Good to know it's not me or my computer that is cursed!

Comment: **NOTE**: looks like this is fixed in more-recent versions of Excel.  See note on linked answer.  Thanks @Notus_Panda for pointing that out.